Monaco diff editor - potential listener LEAK detected
I have to opened 100 instances of Monaco diff editor in my Angular project. If I do this, I get an error in the console about a potential leakage of listeners. Need help on how I can get rid of this error in the console.
Example of Monaco diff editor call:
<div *ngFor="let arr of fakeArray"> <!-- fakeArray = new Array(100) -->
  <k-editor></k-editor> <!-- monaco diff editor component -->
</div>

Chrome console:
core.mjs:6531 ERROR Error: [61d] potential listener LEAK detected, having 200 listeners already. MOST frequent listener (1):

Error
    at Stacktrace.create (event.js:682:21)
    at _a._event [as _onDidChangeLanguages] (event.js:827:46)
    at get onDidChange (languageService.js:100:35)
    at new TextModel (textModel.js:172:75)
    at ModelService._createModelData (modelService.js:253:23)
    at ModelService.createModel (modelService.js:297:30)
    at doCreateModel (standaloneCodeEditor.js:330:25)
    at createTextModel (standaloneCodeEditor.js:324:12)
    at Object.createModel (standaloneEditor.js:180:27)
    at EditorComponent.monacoInit (editor.component.ts:32:31)
    at errors.js:15:27
    at timer (zone.js:2402:41)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:403:31)
    at core.mjs:14511:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:14511:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:36)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:14824:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:36)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:174:47)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:484:34)


I guess this is expected, I found a similar issue on their GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/3895 To avoid this you can implement something like virtual scroll which only renders the visible editors.

I don't know the answer, but the wording of the error suggests that the runtime suspects there's an unintended resource leak.
